# A library for interacting with JPL Horizons

Tags: python, library

I'm writing a tiny Python library that fetches data from Horizons, JPL's solar system data and ephemeris computation service. An overview of their batch CGI is [here](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons_batch.cgi). While the script is simple, I would like to make it as clear and standardized as possible.

The idea is to initialize the HorizonsRequest class with a location for the observer (center), target (COMMAND), datetime, and the the data you want (quantities). The response can be retrieved as either a complete list of the lines sent back or as a dictionary of the requested values.

**Example request**

A request for the angle of Jupiter (599), its distance, and light travel time in relation to Earth (399) at the current time. Horizons users can find these numeric ids using the web-interface.

```
request = horizons.HorizonsRequest("399", "599", datetime.utcnow(), "2,20,21")
request.send()

dictionary = request.get_dictionary()
for key in dictionary:
    print(key, ":", dictionary[key])
```

**Library**

```
import sys
import urllib.request
import math
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_julian_datetime(date):
    # Ensure correct format
    if not isinstance(date, datetime):
        raise TypeError('Invalid type for parameter "date" - expecting datetime')
    elif date.year < 1801 or date.year > 2099:
        raise ValueError('Datetime must be between year 1801 and 2099')

    # Perform the calculation
    julian_datetime = 367 * date.year - int((7 * (date.year + int((date.month + 9) 
    / 12.0))) / 4.0) + int((275 * date.month) / 9.0) + date.day + 1721013.5 
    + (date.hour + date.minute / 60.0 + date.second / math.pow(60,2)) / 24.0 
    - 0.5 * math.copysign(1, 100 * date.year + date.month - 190002.5) + 0.5

    return julian_datetime

class HorizonsRequest:
    def __init__(self, center, target, datetime, quantities):
        self.keys = {
            "CENTER": center,
            "COMMAND": target,
            "QUANTITIES": quantities,
            "TLIST": str(get_julian_datetime(datetime)),
            "MAKE_EPHEM": "YES",
            "OBJ_DATA": "NO",
            "TABLE_TYPE": "OBSERVER",
            "CAL_FORMAT": "BOTH",
            "ANG_FORMAT": "DEG",
            "CSV_FORMAT": "YES"
        }
        self.response = []
        self.dictionary = {}
    
    def set_key(self, key, value):
        self.keys[key] = str(value)

    def delete_key(self, key):
        self.keys.pop(key, None)    

    def send(self):
        # create request
        request = "https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons_batch.cgi?batch=1"
        for key in self.keys:
            request += "&" + key + "='" + self.keys[key] + "'"

        # send request
        file = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
        for line in file:
            self.response.append(line.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', ''))

    def get_dictionary(self):
        keys = []
        values = [] 

        # locate data position in response
        i = 0
        while i < len(self.response):
            if "$$SOE" in self.response[i]:
                keys = self.response[i - 2].split(",")
                values = self.response[i + 1].split(",")
            i += 1

        # create dictionary
        i = 0
        while i < len(keys):
            self.dictionary[keys[i].strip()] = values[i].strip()
            i += 1

        return self.dictionary

    def get_response(self):
        return self.response
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for feedback on the internal code or the external interfacing of your library?

Comment: Internal code mostly, but suggestions regarding better ways to interface with it would also be helpful. The only thing that cannot be changed is the Horizons requests.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Use Requests

`urllib` is kind of a pain to use. Use Requests instead. Among other things, all of this code:

```
    for key in self.keys:
        request += "&" + key + "='" + self.keys[key] + "'"
```

will go away. Requests has query string formatting from a dictionary.

### Julian conversion

It's doubtful that you need to be doing this yourself. Find a library such as https://pypi.org/project/julian/ .

### Combined-inequality syntax

```
date.year < 1801 or date.year > 2099
```

should be

```
not (1800 < date.year < 2100)
```

### Squaring

```
math.pow(60,2)
```

should just be

```
60**2
```

### Late serialization

I would recommend that `HorizonsRequest.keys` (which, by the way, is not only a collection of keys - it's a dictionary, so it's misnamed) not be constructed until it's needed in `send`. Nor should you expose arbitrary `set_key` / `delete_key`. In theory you should understand enough about the request format that information to create it is stored in more strongly-typed variables that can receive better validation. For instance, do not store

```
"OBJ_DATA": "NO",
```

as a class member; instead store

```
obj_data: bool = False
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I'll make these changes. I'll check into Requests and pypi's julian library right away. Regarding the keys, because OBJ_DATA's value must be sent as "NO" should the bool be converted to this format only during request formation?

Comment: _should the bool be converted to this format only during request formation?_ - Yes; I believe this would offer better structure to your program.

Comment: I'm a little curious, regarding python, what people's thoughts are regarding when you should use a library if you can write it yourself. While popular libraries are likely to be better implementations, requiring your users to install another package seems worse sometimes, right? I become worried that someone unfamiliar with python will download my package from git and then be required to also install a bunch of extra things from pip.

Comment: @Pandazoic Python is batteries-included. Use what's available, keep a back-up in case it breaks. Reinventing the wheel is not Pythonic. If you want to make sure the packages are readily available, you can consider copying them into your own library (also takes care of version-difference troubles), make sure you read the relevant licenses first though.

Comment: Ah, good thinking. Yeah that makes sense, like a whole ecosystem, huh? Guess I could include some relevant packages.

Comment: "Requests has query string formatting from a dictionary." IMO it'd have been nice to see this.